# How can I manipulate HTML DOM with data from Database and Node (Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, html, css, mongoose, dom

Following the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3rylF3y3og&ab_channel=TraversyMedia

I'm coding something that has a Star review feature.
I want to change the width (through document.querySelector('').style.width = starPercentage) of elements to determine how many stars a review gave:

```
function getRatings() {
      for (let rating in ratings) {
        // Get percentage
        const starPercentage = (ratings[rating] / starsTotal) * 100;

        // Round to nearest 10
        const starPercentageRounded = `${Math.round(starPercentage / 10) * 10}%`;

        // Set width of stars-inner to percentage
        document.querySelector(`.${rating} .stars-inner`).style.width = starPercentageRounded;

        // Add number rating
        document.querySelector(`.${rating} .number-rating`).innerHTML = ratings[rating];
     }
}
```

But instead of the hard-coded values I'm getting the data from mongoose and express. What's the best way to manipulate the stars of each review?

Comment: Can you share the overall HTML structure you currently have and what exactly you are trying to achieve? I mean why do you want to manipulate the width of the stars section in the first place? It makes much more sense to show like 5 stars for each review and fill that many of them that are rated like 3/5.

Comment: https://youtu.be/u3rylF3y3og - im using this video as reference, I just want to know how i can change the width, as shown in the video, but the data comes from mongoose.

Comment: <div class="stars-inner" style="<%= review.ratingPercentage %>"></div> i tried changing the style this way, but it seems that the style="" part wont allow me to embed the width with EJS, any solutions?

Comment: You didn't specified that you're using templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

The following article contains simple technique for filling star ratings in Javascript. https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-simple-javascript-technique-for-filling-star-ratings--cms-29450

Comment: instead of using EJS use Javascript Template Literals to change the value in style i.e. style=`${review.ratingPercentage}`  See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_templates.asp for more information.

Answer (score -1):

CSS

and add the correct css to the html class tag for example ( ,   ....)

Comment: <div class="2-stars"> </div>

Comment: That doesn't correspond to the font-awesome library which topic starter uses.